# ionic 3 / Cordova : Build an app which being supported by all android versions from 2.0 to 7.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-version

I start developping with Ionic, so I installed the lastest versions of Ionic and Cordova.

```
Cordova : 8.0.0
Ionic : 3.19.1
```

In the Cordova Documentation there is a mapping between cordova versions and android API Levels:

```
cordova API-Levels  Equivalent Android Version
6.X.X   16 - 25     4.1 - 7.1.1
5.X.X   14 - 23     4.0 - 6.0.1
4.1.X   14 - 22     4.0 - 5.1
4.0.X   10 - 22     2.3.3 - 5.1
3.7.X   10 - 21     2.3.3 - 5.0.2
```

Documentation Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

When I start to test my first App in the different android version,

Android 5 : OK 
Android 2.3 : NOK (Error in Android Studio when running the app in my real device : the minSdk supported = 16 > your device sdk (10)

So I'm asking if want that my application been supported by all android versions from android 2.0.0 to android 7.0.0, What I have to do ?

Thank you for your support

Comment: There are few devices running versions prior to Android 4.1. Hopefully, there are no active devices running Android 2.0, as that would be a ~9 year old device.

Comment: @CommonsWare In poor countries, they still use devices running lower android versions and I want that my App cover them

Comment: Very little of Android development supports back that far. Apparently, Cordova does not support back that far. Google, on the whole, stopped supporting app development for API levels below 15 about 18 months ago. So, you will have a difficult time doing what you want.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your support (y)